# Finding a Specific Distance with Limited Rate Information

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the problem below, I have rearranged the information in every way that I can think of and found the average rate and average time but I am stumped.  I seem to be going in circles. I even put it aside for a day or so but I keep getting sucked back into the same black hole.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Bob travels at a constant speed from point $A$ to point $B$ which is $6$ miles away.  When he reaches point $B$, he immediately turns around and rides back to point $A$ at a constant speed $40\%$ slower than his previous speed.  At the moment exactly halfway between the time Bob leaves point $A$ and the time he returns to point $A$, how far (in miles) is he from point $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t_1$ = time from A to B, $t_2$ = time from B to A.
$vt_1 = 6 = .6vt_2, t_1 = .6t_2$
$(t_1 + t_2)/2 = .8t_2 = .6t_2 + .2t_2$
By half time Bob has scampered from A to B and 20% of
the way back leaving Bob stranded at .2×6 miles from B.

Answer (score 0):

The total time from A to B and back to A is

$$ T= \frac dv + \frac d{0.4v} = \frac72 \frac dv $$

The time travelled from B to the half time moment is

$$ t = \frac T2 - \frac dv = \frac34 \frac dv $$

Thus, the distance from B is

$$0.4v t = 0.3d= 1.8 \> miles$$